How to update the clouflare manged rules using api endpoint
I want to override the Existing Cloudflare managed rule. I have gone through the document.
In the document, I found the below example
"action_parameters": {
"id": "<RULESET_ID>",
"overrides": {
// ruleset overrides
"property-to-modify": "value",
"property-to-modify": "value",
// tag overrides
"categories": [
  {
    "category": "<TAG_NAME>",
    "property-to-modify": "value",
    "property-to-modify": "value"
  }
],
// rule overrides
"rules": [
  {
    "id": "<RULE_ID>",
    "property-to-modify": "value",
    "property-to-modify": "value"
  }
]

}
}
Can someone help me to put some real examples? How to post this body using postman.
my existing rule looks like this below
{
"result": {
    "id": "77454feXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name": "Cloudflare Managed Free Ruleset",
    "description": "Created by the Cloudflare security team, this ruleset is designed to provide protection for free zones",
    "source": "firewall_managed",
    "kind": "managed",
    "version": "56",
    "rules": [
        {
            "id": "b453c8ace3YYYYYYYYYYY",
            "version": "55",
            "action": "block",
            "categories": [
                "cve-2021-44832",
                "cve-2021-45105",
                "log4j",
                "rce"
            ],
            "description": "Log4j Headers",
            "last_updated": "2023-10-11T14:34:33.86359Z",
            "ref": "147f48YYYIIPIUPUPUPPPU",
            "enabled": true}

So based on the cloudflare example I just need to update the override configuration it can be any action like simulate or block any example will work for me..
